# using Complex in MatchQ

Tags: pattern-matching, complex

Can anyone explain me the use of `Complex` in this example:

`MatchQ[a,d_.*Complex[0,c_]]`

Comment: match complex number with only imaginary part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Complex[0, c_]` means: match only complex numbers whose real part is exactly `0`

The `d_.*` means: allow optional multiplication (like `-Pi I`).

So,

```
MatchQ[#, d_. Complex[0, c_]] & /@ {I, -I, 2 I, -Pi I}
```

> {True, True, True, True}

but

```
MatchQ[#, d_. Complex[0, c_]] & /@ {1 + I, a + I}
```

> {False, False}

Furthermore,

```
MatchQ[2. I, d_. Complex[0, c_]]
```

> False

but

```
MatchQ[2. I, d_. Complex[0 | 0., c_]]
```

> True